# How to serialize/deserialize object that contains collection of various objects to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, collections

I want to serialize a class that is basically a container of other items. These items are various objects but they all inherit from one common class. It will be more clear with the example.

I have this in code:

```cs
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(FileTask))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DbTask))]
[XmlRoot("task")]
public abstract class TaskBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TaskBase()
    {
        Name = "Task";
    }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("fileTask")]
public class FileTask : TaskBase
{
    public FileTask()
    {
        Name = "File Task";
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("dbTask")]
public class DbTask : TaskBase
{
    public DbTask()
    {
        Name = "Db Task";
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("tasks")]
public class TasksConfig : List<TaskBase>
{

}
```

And when I serialize it to XML with this code:

```cs
        var config = new TasksConfig();
        config.Add(new FileTask());
        config.Add(new FileTask());
        config.Add(new DbTask());
        config.Add(new FileTask());
        config.Add(new DbTask());
        SerializationHelper.SaveToXml<TasksConfig>(config, "milos.xml");
```

with this helper class:

```cs
 public class SerializationHelper
{
    static public void SaveToXml<T>(T obj, string file)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tasks>
  <TaskBase d2p1:type="FileTask" name="File Task" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <TaskBase d2p1:type="FileTask" name="File Task" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <TaskBase d2p1:type="DbTask" name="Db Task" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <TaskBase d2p1:type="FileTask" name="File Task" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <TaskBase d2p1:type="DbTask" name="Db Task" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
</tasks>
```

However, I want to get this result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tasks>
  <fileTask name="File Task" />
  <fileTask name="File Task" />
  <dbTask name="Db Task" />
  <fileTask name="File Task" />
  <dbTask name="Db Task" />
</tasks>
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another variant is change `TaskConfig` class like this

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("tasks")]
public class TasksConfig
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(DbTask)), XmlElement(typeof(FileTask))]
    public List<TaskBase> list = new List<TaskBase>();

    public void Add(TaskBase item){
        list.Add(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your `TasksConfig` class source.

Make it like this:

```
public class TaskConfig() 
{
    public TaskConfig()
    {
       this.Items = new List<TaskBase>();
    }

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="FileTask", Type=typeof(FileTask))]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="DbTask", Type=typeof(DbTask))]
    public List<TaskBase> Items
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}
```

Then, for serializing it, you could do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new TasksConfig();
    config.Items.Add( new FileTask() { /* properties */ });
    config.Items.Add( new DbTask() { /* properties */ });

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TasksConfig));
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, config);

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    String serializedString = enc.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```